# 20.04 Printer driver for epson stylus photo r 285

Tags: drivers, printing, epson

I have run printers in Ubuntu since 2006. I upgraded from 19.10 to the recent **20.04** and found printer error requesting to download a Gutenprint driver. I followed that but no working driver
(5.0.1-1lsb3.1_amd64.deb) had been installed.  Most references on Google are years out of date.
I have downloaded (ie mislead) a pips-3.0-1.src.rpm file but not certain in installing that as as no amd64 deb file was downloaded.
The onboard Ubuntu Help has no suggestions.  Epson has no linux drivers.
What happened to the drivers that worked painlessly before? Can I get those back,'cups' was a buzword that comes to mind.
Sorry Ubuntu I need some help please to get the Epson Stylus Photo R 285 USB printer up and running

Answer (score 1):

Execute `lpinfo -m | grep R285`. This gives you a PPD. It ends with *expert*.

Execute `lpinfo -v`. This gives you a URI. It probably begins with *usb:/*.

Now **substitute** for PPD and URI in `lpadmin -p r285 -v URI -E -m PPD`

Test with `lp -d r285 /etc/nsswitch.conf`.

It work's?